# Echarts.js Library - Referencing pages using onclick event for pie slices

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am using the echarts.js library for pie charts,

I would like to make each slice in the pie hyperlink to another page.

Im using static data points for now, to test if it will work - and will update to dynamic data after.

Below is an example of pie1a - i would like T2, T2, T4 and N/A to reference their own pages. T2 = "http://localhost/T2.html".

//ECHART_PIE1a

```
  var echartPie1a = echarts.init(document.getElementById('echart_pie1a'), theme);

  echartPie1a.setOption({
     tooltip: {
      trigger: 'item',
      formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"

    },




    legend: {
      x: 'right',
      y: 'bottom',
       data: ['T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'N/A']
    },

    calculable: true,
    series: [{
      name: '(TB)',
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '54%',
      center: ['54%', '36%'],
      data: [{

        value: 438,
        name: 'T2'
      }, {
        value: 1109,
        name: 'T3'
      }, {
        value: 42,
        name: 'T4'
      }, {
        value: 389,
        name: 'N/A'

      }]
    }]
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
echartPie1a.setOption(option);
echartPie1a.on('click', function (params) 
{window.open('' + encodeURIComponent(params.name) + '.html', '_self');
});
```

**Seems to have done the trick.**